# Storing data in cookies,client side verification

Tags: javascript, forms, function, cookies, form-submit

I have created a registration form.i have set the cookies,now my question is, when i click on submit button,all the details which user has given has to be stored in the next page using cookies.how do i proceed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle form submit and store all the details which user has given into cookies.

```js
forms.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  // Handle your data and store them in cookies then you can use them in next page
});
```

Hope you only use this for learning or development purposes, this is not a good way to handle a registration form!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than cookies I prefer [localStorage](https://javascript.info/localstorage).
you can just store user token in localStorage using `setItem()` method and delete data for logouts using `removeItem()`. If you  want to see if token is still there in localStorage you use `getItem()` method.